# How to properly select just a number of rows in between in Oracle 11.g?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

For now this is the code I'm using:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT product.*, rownum AS n
  FROM product
) WHERE n >= 4 AND n < 4+2;
```

This selects 2 rows from the table product starting to count by row number 4 (included).

And it works fine BUT the final select will also show a column for the rownum.
The only workaround I have for now is to manually type the columns that I want in the main Select, but what if I didn't know the names and amount of columns?
Is there a nicer way to do this?
Many thanks

Comment: Yes, explicitly listing all columns in the outer select is your only option. Using `select *` in production code (that is not just an ad-hoc query) isn't good coding style anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont want to write all column names then you need to join your query with your `table` again using PK. (As I dont think that there is another way in oracle 11g to exclude `rn` from final result except writing all the column names manually)

```
SELECT T.* FROM
(SELECT PK_COLUMN
FROM (
  SELECT product.PK_COLUMN, rownum AS n
  FROM product
) WHERE n >= 4 AND n < 4+2) P
JOIN T ON T.PK_COLUMN = P.PK_COLUMN
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for!! I'm sad that there is no easier way to do that in Oracle 11. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What I am wondering here is, you are not using any `ORDER BY` clause. Without using `ORDER BY` clause rows can be returned in any order. So basically your query is similar to -

```
SELECT product.*
FROM product
WHERE rownum <= 3;
```

Comment: In Oracle rownum does not refer to the number of the row in the table, but to how many rows have been already selected. So rownum >= 4 won't ever work because there never were rows 1 2 and 3 selected

Comment: @DavidM.Casas, You are absolutely right. So basically your query is just `rownum <= 3;`

Comment: But what to do if I want to skip the first n selected? I want my select to skip up to the 4th valid select, and then select 4th and 5th row. It works the way I posted in the main post but I don't know if theres a nicer way to do it

Comment: As I have already told you, There is no 4th or 5th row until you have an order by clause. Once you have that also, You can refer Tejash's answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry if my wording was not right, indeed Tejash's answer was what I was looking for